# Invoking a method in a generic Blazor child control

Tags: blazor

Invoking a method in a generic child control

I have a container control called InfoPanel, which should hold instances of other controls of various types, but all derived from a base class called InfoPanelControl. InfoPanelControl defines a virtual method Save.

I want to call contained control’s Save method from InfoPanel, so that each concrete control would do its own specific saving.

This is how it looks:

```
<InfoPanel>
    <Budget />
</InfoPanel>
```

Here Budget is derived from InfoPanelControl.

InfoPanel has a ChildControl property:

```
[Parameter] private RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

Which is populated with the instances of child controls, in this example it’s Budget.

Now, I need to access the Budget control (as a InfoPanelControl, because I don’t need the specific type, only the base type) from InfoPanel. In InfoPanel I was hoping to do the following:

```
InfoPanelControl childControl = ChildContent.Target as InfoPanelControl;
```

However, what ChildContent.Target returns is not the Budget casted to InfoPanelControl. It’s actually the instance of a higher level control that is the container of InfoPanel.

How can I access the methods of the Budget (casted to InfoPanelControl) control from InfoPanel?

Comment: Your current syntax allows more than one InfoPanelControl, and it allows markup around it. Do you need all that?  Otherwise, `<InfoPanel Control=aBudget />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, I actually did something similar a few days ago. I ended up using a cascading parameter/value to solve my particular issue. 
I've used a simple example below to show the general logic.

I expect that in the future there will be a better solution to this, but at time of writing blazor is still in preview.

I would also recommend having a ChildControlBase that implements the interface which all the child controls inherit from.

The additional 'good thing' about this implementation is that it will work for multiple child components that may be in the 'ChildContent' and the markup around it doesnt matter.

I currently add the child to the parent in the override of OnParametersSet. Depending on your needs you may want to use this differently or have additional logic.

ParentControlBase.cs

```
    public class ParentControlBase : ComponentBase
{
    private List<IDoSomething> _childControls;

    public ParentControlBase()
    {
        _childControls = new List<IDoSomething>();
    }

    public void AddChildControl(IDoSomething control)
    {
        if (!_childControls.Contains(control))
        {
            _childControls.Add(control); 
        }
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnRelevantChildControls()
    {
        foreach (var control in _childControls)
        {
            control.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

ParentControl.razor

```
@inherits ParentControlBase
<div class="parent-control-container">
<div>Parent Control</div>
    <CascadingValue Name="IDoSomethingParentControl" value="@this">
        @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
    <div class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@DoSomethingOnRelevantChildControls">Do Something</div>
</div>
@code{
    [Parameter]
    private RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Common Child Control Implementation

```
   public interface IDoSomething
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }
```

ChildControl

```
@implements IDoSomething
<div>ChildControl</div>

@code
{

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "IDoSomethingParentControl")]
    private ParentControlBase CurrentParentControl { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (CurrentParentControl != null)
        {
            CurrentParentControl.AddChildControl(this);
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do Something implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your implementation. After posting the question, I proceeded with an ugly implementation, where I just manually wired up the parent and the child in the container's OnAfterRender. It works, but your implementation, although essentially doing the same thing, is definitely more generic and robust then mine; from your code I also learned that I can pass object references via cascading parameters (something I didn't realize before). I will use your idea - thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

ChildContent.Target property returns an **instance of the generated class** on which the current RenderFragment delegate invokes the instance method that renders the content. In this case, since infoPanel defines a ChildContent property, ChildContent.Target returns the container component of infoPanel, and not Budget. ChildContent.Target is set by the compiler and you can't do anything about it. Actually, not much can be done with regards to the RenderFragment delegate, and it provides very little discoverability mechanism.

Your scheme is too sophisticated, at least for the time being, for Blazor... 
I'd suggest the following implementation instead:  Expose a Save event raised in your infoPanel component, and propagated (notify) to subscribers ( child components.). This is a much less sophisticated solution, yet I find your question very intriguing, and hope to see it solved the way you initially wanted. Perhaps you should try your luck in github... very often Steve Anderson solve such issues.

Hope this helps...